What are the differences between "Christianity Stack Exchange" and "Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange"?
Can someone please explain what the differences are between the "Christianity Stack Exchange" and the "Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange"? Can you give examples? Can specialized religious beliefs be referred to?

Christianity Stack Exchange from help:

Christianity Stack Exchange is for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more. You may ask questions about any area of Christianity. Your own beliefs do not not preclude you from asking questions, but all questions must be directly related to Christianity.
You've come to the right place if you have questions about:

the history of denominations (such as Roman Catholic, Anglican, Church of Christ, or Latter Day Saints) and movements (such as Pentecostalism, Creationism, or Calvinism)
understanding the Bible from the perspective of a specific viewpoint (like those listed above)
explanations of the beliefs and practices of a denomination or movement
the biblical basis for a belief or practice

However, there are questions that are not constructive for the format of this site. These include questions asking for:

a straw poll of views on a particular subject
what the Bible says about a subject (unless you specify a doctrine/tradition)
advice on how to handle certain situations (pastoral advice questions)
open-ended is "X" a sin questions, asking whether a certain action or belief is sinful (unless focused on the teaching of a specific group)
"Truth" questions that do not focus on what a specific group of people teaches
whether some group or person is "Christian"

These types of questions have too many possible answers (many of which will be pure opinion). Because of that, these types of questions are not constructive for this site and will be closed as such.

Biblical Hermeneutics from help:

Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange is for anyone who wants to explore what a Biblical text means (exegesis) using techniques or rules of interpretation (hermeneutics).
We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist and other viewpoints as long as they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts. The answers we rate most highly stem from and work up from the text.
If your question is about...

interpretation of a specific Bible passage
hermeneutical approaches
translation of Biblical texts
historical context (with regards to a particular text)
source criticism
... then this is the right place to ask.


